# fancybox not open until mouse pointer move physically

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

**Scenario:**

I have gallery page in which different images paste on screen, when i
click an
image,   fancy box open with next and previous buttons and user can move next and back
to view all images in fancy box

**Problem**

Fancy box not open until I move mouse pointer physically on
selected image during test run or set the mouse pointer on screen
where selected image   will display before test run

```
 WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[2]/p/a/span"));
    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    builder.moveToElement(el).click();
    builder.perform();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    
    
    // following code add to move mouse pointer physically but its also not working
    
    Point coordinates = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[2]/p/a/span")).getLocation();
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.mouseMove(coordinates.getX(),coordinates.getY()+120);
```

Comment: In scenario you mentioned as `After clicks an image a fancy box will open`. But, in the code why are you trying to move the mouse pointer to the element and then performing click action. There is a conflict between two.

Answer (score 0):

Webdriver can click on elements without the use of `Actions`. Try if the following snippet works for you.

```
WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[2]/p/a/span"));
el.click();
```

If not, verify your xpath once and post the errors you get.

Also, you have added the impicit wait after performing your click actions. That's not going to introduce any waits for the click command itself. Implicit wait is associated with the lifetime of the `driver` variable and ideally should be added when the `driver` was instantiated.

If you need to waits which are customized for every action, try using `Explicit Waits`.